# email using php

Tags: php, email

I want to send email using the php code, Following is the code should validate and also sends email to myemail.com. However, it is not working.

I am new to php. any help appreciated!!!!

```
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Subject here...";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form your submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    ) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form your submitted.');      
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['email']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
  if(!eregi($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "^[a-z .'-]+$";
  if(!eregi($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $email_message = "Email body here......\n\n";



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

Comment: What is not working?  Are you getting an error message or just not receiving the email?

Comment: Remove the @ from the `mail()` function, and echo out what `mail()` returns. If it returns false or NULL, its not sending.

Comment: pardon me if it is silly, however, what i did is: echo mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  and it did not do anything about it

Comment: Are you ever actually calling your died function with the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script was not able to read values from $_POST['email'], I changed it to $_REQUEST['email'],, and so on for all values and it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of configuration `sendmail_path`? (See `phpinfo()` or php.ini)
Can you run the application that is set in said configuration?

Comment: Just write `die(phpinfo());` at the very beginning of your script, call it and then look for "sendmail_path" in the output.

Comment: Oh, and if your server is on Windows, look for "SMTP", too.

Comment: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i both local and master values... excuse me for naive questions.. I havent worked on php before this.. any help appreciated!!!

Comment: If you have shell access run "mail your@address.com", enter subject and text, end it with "." (a single dot on a line) and look if you get the mail.